# .htaccess authentication with nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I've some issues with my configuration. I'm using Nginx as a reversed proxy for my Apache server. My website has .htaccess authentication but Nginx doesn't seem to understand it so I'm getting a 404 error.

I saw some translators on other answers but it doesn't translate this part.

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/mywebsite/private/.htpassword
AuthName "Acces Restreint" 
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

By the way, do you have any idea about how to translate this second part ?

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

Thanks everyone for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for perfomance related issues, [nginx by default does not look up per-directory .htaccess files](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess), which is a problem if your hosting does not let you edit webserver config.

if you can edit webserver config (or put new config into conf.d dir)
just add these lines, replacing /your/path correspondingly

```
 location  /your/path  {
   auth_basic            "Acces Restreint";
   auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/mywebsite/private/.htpassword;
 }
```

answering second part of your question needs more info on how you use PHP with nginx.
if you are tied to FastCGI (e.g. php-fpm), then you can use this method to set PHP' vars:

```
 fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "session.gc_maxlifetime=604800";


 env APPLICATION_ENV development;
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. That makes sense. Fortunately, I have all roots privileges to edit my webserver config !

PHP is working with Apache. Nginx is just used as reversed proxy.